# Confusing super keyword in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two code blocks, which I believe is the same, but they result in different output.

**Code block 1**

```
class GP:

    def __init__(self):
        print("GP")


class P1(GP):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("P1")


class P2(GP):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("P2")


class C(P1, P2):

    def __init__(self):
        P1.__init__(self)
        P2.__init__(self)
        print("C")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    C()
```

The output for this is

> GP P2 P1 GP P2 C

**Code block 2**

```
class GP:

    def __init__(self):
        print("GP")


class P1(GP):

    def __init__(self):
        GP.__init__(self)
        print("P1")


class P2(GP):

    def __init__(self):
        GP.__init__(self)
        print("P2")


class C(P1, P2):

    def __init__(self):
        P1.__init__(self)
        P2.__init__(self)
        print("C")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    C()
```

For this the output is

> GP P1 GP P2 C

My expected behaviour is code block 2.
I am confused as to why code block 1 results in this output.

This question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) looks to be a similar question, but in this question, my doubt is regarding the difference between both these approaches in this exact scenario.